# Java Non Heap Memory - How to reduce it

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

We run Tomcat on our server with several Java Apps configured as Virtual Hosts. It has been running quite well for several months with very little or no swap on vmstat, but recently vmstat has been jumping to more than 500 MB under similar load conditions.

Following is the output of JVM Top tool and vmstat. I see that Non-Heap memory is significantly higher than Heap which is quite unexpected from our application stand point.

Can someone give pointers on how to go about fixing it. The app runs on a remote server so using a graphical tool is not possible.

```
 PID 28085: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
 ARGS: start
 VMARGS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properti[...]
 VM: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0
 UP: 105:58m #THR: 49   #THRPEAK: 85   #THRCREATED: 4362 USER: root
 GC-Time:  0: 6m   #GC-Runs: 3058      #TotalLoadedClasses: 108669
 CPU:  0.00% GC:  0.00% HEAP: 260m / 989m NONHEAP: 733m /1072m

  TID   NAME                                    STATE    CPU  TOTALCPU BLOCKEDBY
 Note: Only top 10 threads (according cpu load) are shown!
[2J[H JvmTop 0.8.0 alpha - 17:05:06,  amd64,  1 cpus, Linux 2.6.18-23, load avg 1.55
 http://code.google.com/p/jvmtop

 PID 28085: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
 ARGS: start
 VMARGS: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properti[...]
 VM: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0
 UP: 105:58m #THR: 49   #THRPEAK: 85   #THRCREATED: 4362 USER: root
 GC-Time:  0: 6m   #GC-Runs: 3058      #TotalLoadedClasses: 108671
 CPU:  3.26% GC:  0.00% HEAP: 261m / 989m NONHEAP: 733m /1072m

  TID   NAME                                    STATE    CPU  TOTALCPU BLOCKEDBY
   4368 RMI TCP Connection(111)-XXX.XX       RUNNABLE  3.98%     0.00%
   4369 JMX server connection timeout   TIMED_WAITING  0.12%     0.00%
     45 http-bio-/127.0.0.1-8080-Async  TIMED_WAITING  0.00%     0.20%
     47 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-AsyncT  TIMED_WAITING  0.00%     0.20%
   4364 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2       RUNNABLE  0.00%     0.00%
   4363 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2       RUNNABLE  0.00%     0.00%
   4353 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2       RUNNABLE  0.00%     0.01%
   4338 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2       RUNNABLE  0.00%     0.01%
   4337 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2       RUNNABLE  0.00%     0.00%
   4336 ajp-bio-/127.0.0.1-8009-exec-2       RUNNABLE  0.00%     0.01%
 Note: Only top 10 threads (according cpu load) are shown!
```

Output of vmstat

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0 491540  35152  38404 240572    2    1   283   222    4    2  7  1 87  5  0
 0  0 491540  34920  38512 240864   32    0   380     0  223  375 20  1 46 33  0
 0  0 491540  34920  38512 240864    0    0     0     0  105   64  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 491540  34920  38512 240904    0    0     0    16  109   67  0  0 100  0  0
 0  0 491540  34860  38540 240952    0    0    48     0  132  154  4  5 87  5  0
```

Comment: Which version of tomcat is this? How long has it been running? It's quite likely you are running into the permgenspace memory leak issue.

Comment: Do you stop and start applications fairly regularly?

Comment: Some builds of tomcat have an issue where redeploying webapps (reloading contexts) leads to more and more PermGenSpace being allocated and said space never being released. There are some workarounds to this issue.

Comment: It's Tomcat 7.0.21. Yes, we do replace some classes in App path (WEB-INF/classes) which triggers a reload of the application. On average we may do it 2-3 times/day. Can you tell me what is the workaround to fixing PermGenSpace leak issue.

Comment: You need to do a heapdump and work out what's hanging around. **This almost certainly not a tomcat issue** - read [this article](http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/) on why leaks happen and how to track them down. Essentialy _something_ is keeping the webapp's classloader from being garbage collected, and the classloader holds references to all the webapp's classes. You need to track that something down.